# Caching de-attached Hibernate entities in external Cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching

I have a set of very heavy queries whose result I want to cache into an external Cache implementation (cache the whole object list not just ids like in Hibernate's 2nd level cache).

The issue is that due to the lazy loading of several collections in the root object, once the session that queried the results is done, the objects become de-attached and the next request that tries to use the object might throw a LazyLoading exception.

Environment: Spring 4, Hibernate 4.3, Ehcache.

Is there any way to be able to re-attach the object to a new session without having it modify the underlaying DB (like with merge and update)?

Comment: to reattach detached objects to a session, use merge and take the return value of the merge call, that is the attached object.

Comment: the 2nd level does not cache only the Ids, it caches also the data - have a look at http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html, it's the query cache that only caches Ids or primitive values as result of query. The id's will then be resolved against the second level cache that contains the data

Comment: Sure... but for collections it does save only the identifiers. The issue in the question is not regarding the non complex types, but the collections that can yield a LazyLoading exception. Also, if I use merge any out of date data in the de-attached object will replace the data in the object within the session.

Comment: for collections it does save only the identifiers, which then are resolved against 2nd level cache if the association itself is marked with @Cache, as associations per default are not cached even if both linked entities are cached

Comment: I have added an answer to main question of reattaching object without merge. but I think that due to some pitfall misunderstanding about the 2nd level cache you would be trying to reimplement it yourself, the blog post i linked is really a great read it would clear a lot of confusion - hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to reattach a detached entity to a session just to load a lazy-initialized collection.

In order to get an updated copy of a persistent object without overwriting the session / calling merge, it's necessary to call `either EntityManager.find()` or do a query.

This is because the main goal of the session is to keep the database and the objects in memory in sync. Due to this there is no API for attaching new state without persisting it, as this is not in line with the main functionality of the session.

The 2nd level cache, if configured together with the query cache can solve the problem of caching the entities, queries and their associations in a much better way than any custom solution.

Everything can get cached to the point that no query hits the database. The two caches really go together, check this [blog post](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html) for further info.